# Best approach for handling array out of bounds or negative array index

Tags: c, arrays

I have defined an enum which maps to string array. I will get this string as a parameter to a function which shall return the enum value. This value is used as an index to another array.

Function looks something like this

```
int get_unit_id(char * name);
```

If the name is not found in the array, function returns -1. Although, this case never arises in the current setup, static analysis tool is throwing an error saying array index can be negative. How do I deal with this ?

I also considered returning the ID of MAX element of the enum, but this would result in array out of bounds warning

EDIT : Added Code for reference.
Checking the return value of the function is not feasible as the function is being called from lot of places and it would increase the number of LOC a lot.

```
int get_unit_id(const char * name)
   {
       int index;

       for (index = 0; index < UNIT_MAX_UNITS; index++){
           if(!strcmp(name, unit_map[index].unit_name)){
               return unit_map[index].unit_id;
           }
       }
       printf("Didn't find Unit %s, returning -1\n",name);
       return -1;
  }
```

Comment: Are you checking if the return value is -1 before using it as an index?

Comment: Can we have at least the code where the error is detected ? Because from what you say, you just iterate througth an array, there is no reason to deal with "negative index".

Comment: I suspect the analysis tool is not complaining about `index` being negative in the `get_unit_id` function, but rather would the caller of that function is doing  when -1 is returned.

Comment: Or it could just be a false positive returned by the analysis tool. If you can't suppress the tool's warning, easier approach might be to just declare `index` as `unsigned int`

Comment: The error is comming from which line of code ? Because I don't see any problem here. I suspect dbush to have correctly guessed your problem : You call the function `get_unit_id` directly in an array, without checking before hand if the function return -1 or not. Could you provide the line where you call the function ?

Comment: Final possibility. Rather than return `-1`, just `assert(false)`. If it's as you say, the lookup should never fail, returning -1 likely will just create hard to find bugs in your code if the caller isn't explicitly handling that possibility. Better to crash when the impossible condition actually happens than to keep going.

Comment: If I understand your question and you are doing `array[get_unit_id(char *name)]` in multiple places all over your code, and there is a possibility `get_unit_id` returns `-1`, there is no way around it, you are going to have to modify each call and  pre-test the return. If you use an `errno` type global, you still have to call `get_unit_id` before passing it as an index; you can't `longjmp` out of the problem in a way more graceful than just exiting. The other option is with an `errno` type global set and return `0` and then catch the error after the `array[get_unit_id(char *name)]`.

Answer (score 1):

The static analysis tool is rightfully flagging the possible use of a negative index if you're not bothering to check if the result is negative before using it as an array index.

You can get around this if you have a special element of the array as a catch-all for an unknown name and return the index of that one instead of -1.

For example:

```
struct map {
    char *unit_name;
    int unit_id;
};

struct map unit_map[UNIT_MAX_UNITS+1] = {
    { "value_0", 0 },
    { "value_1", 1 },
    ...
    { "value_UNIT_MAX_UNITS-1", UNIT_MAX_UNITS-1 },
    { "unknown", UNIT_MAX_UNITS },
};
```

Then in your function:

```
int get_unit_id(const char * name)
{
   int index;

   for (index = 0; index < UNIT_MAX_UNITS; index++){
       if(!strcmp(name, unit_map[index].unit_name)){
           return unit_map[index].unit_id;
       }
   }
   printf("Didn't find Unit %s, returning UNIT_MAX_UNITS\n",name);
   return unit_map[UNIT_MAX_UNITS].unit_id;
}
```

Comment: I see where you are going with that, but in addition to the `printf` of the error message, wouldn't you still have to set some `errno` type global and catch the error after the `array[get_unit_id(..)]` call before it can do damage by propagating a value not based on the string? (it was based on your return value substituted for `-1` -- or am I just missing the point?)